# Vba days in week in another week

Tags: vba, excel, date, drop-down-menu

Currently I have this:

```
Now() - Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) + 1
```

The problem is, if I use a different week, the same date still shows.

I have a dropdownlist that shows me the days from the week I select. Now it selects it from this week, so also in week 1 the date of monday is already the 9th.

How it should be:
I select a weeknumber and the dates that correspondent with that weeknumber need to be shown in the dropdownlist.

Can somebody please help me? I really don't know what to do..

Comment: The case is that you use Now() function which returns current date. You need to refer to the week or day you take from dropdown list. Can you share details regardin dropdown list and the form of dates there? And also references of dropdown list?

Comment: @Rufus I've got  StartDate = Now() - Weekday(Now(), vbMonday) + 1
        
        getWeekDatums = getWeekDatums & CStr(Format(StartDate, "dd-mm-yyyy")) in the code which is called by the dropdownlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this, if I've got you.

```
Function FirstMondayInWeek(intWeekNum As Integer) As Date

Dim d As Date

d = DateSerial(Year(Now) - 1, 12, 31)

Do Until Weekday(d, vbMonday) = 1
    d = d + 1
Loop

FirstMondayInWeek = DateAdd("WW", intWeekNum - 1, d)

End Function
```